# How to add upcoming periods Excel/VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following test dataset:

| Product | Period | Cost | End date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01-01-2022 | 100 | 01-01-2023 |
| B | 01-01-2022 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| C | 01-01-2022 | 290 | 01-05-2023 |

And I want to create the following with Excel or VBA: enrich the dataset with the upcoming periods (like a forecast) until the End date with the same costs. It doesn't have to be in a specific chronological order but the output should be something like this:

| Product | Period | Cost | End date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01-01-2022 | 100 | 01-01-2023 |
| A | 01-02-2022 | 100 | 01-01-2023 |
| A | 01-03-2022 | 100 | 01-01-2023 |
| A | 01-04-2022 | 100 | 01-01-2023 |
| A | 01-05-2022 | 100 | 01-01-2023 |
| A | 01-06-2022 | 100 | 01-01-2023 |
| A | 01-07-2022 | 100 | 01-01-2023 |
| A | 01-08-2022 | 100 | 01-01-2023 |
| A | 01-09-2022 | 100 | 01-01-2023 |
| A | 01-10-2022 | 100 | 01-01-2023 |
| A | 01-11-2022 | 100 | 01-01-2023 |
| A | 01-12-2022 | 100 | 01-01-2023 |
| B | 01-01-2022 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-01-2022 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-02-2022 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-03-2022 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-04-2022 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-05-2022 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-06-2022 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-07-2022 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-08-2022 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-09-2022 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-10-2022 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-11-2022 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-12-2022 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-01-2023 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-01-2023 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-02-2023 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-03-2023 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-04-2023 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-05-2023 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-06-2023 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-07-2023 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-08-2023 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-09-2023 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-10-2023 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-11-2023 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| B | 01-12-2023 | 75 | 01-01-2024 |
| C | 01-01-2022 | 290 | 01-05-2023 |
| C | 01-02-2022 | 290 | 01-05-2023 |
| C | 01-03-2022 | 290 | 01-05-2023 |
| C | 01-04-2022 | 290 | 01-05-2023 |
| C | 01-05-2022 | 290 | 01-05-2023 |
| C | 01-06-2022 | 290 | 01-05-2023 |
| C | 01-07-2022 | 290 | 01-05-2023 |
| C | 01-08-2022 | 290 | 01-05-2023 |
| C | 01-09-2022 | 290 | 01-05-2023 |
| C | 01-10-2022 | 290 | 01-05-2023 |
| C | 01-11-2022 | 290 | 01-05-2023 |
| C | 01-12-2022 | 290 | 01-05-2023 |
| C | 01-01-2023 | 290 | 01-05-2023 |
| C | 01-02-2023 | 290 | 01-05-2023 |
| C | 01-03-2023 | 290 | 01-05-2023 |
| C | 01-04-2023 | 290 | 01-05-2023 |

How do I get this done in Excel? Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for your question! It's because the period 01-12-2023 stands for the month december. The end date is 01-01-2024 so the last month I should calculate is 01-12-2023 (month-1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `F1`:

```
=LET(a,DATEDIF(B2:B4,D2:D4,"m"),b,SCAN(0,a,LAMBDA(X,Y,X+Y)),c,SEQUENCE(SUM(a)),d,INDEX(A2:D4,XMATCH(c,b,1),{1,2,3,4}),e,SCAN(EOMONTH(B2,-1),c,LAMBDA(f,g,IF(INDEX(d,MAX(g-1,1),1)=INDEX(d,g,1),EOMONTH(f,0)+1,INDEX(d,g,2)))),VSTACK(A1:D1,CHOOSECOLS(HSTACK(d,e),{1,5,3,4})))
```

Comment: Hi JvdV, thanks for your response! I have tried the formula but I get a #VALUE error with the following formula (I had to replace the comma's with semicolon in my Excel version): =LET(a;DATEDIF(B2:B4;D2:D4;"m");b;SCAN(0;a;LAMBDA(X;Y;X+Y));c;SEQUENCE(SUM(a));d;INDEX(A2:D4;XMATCH(c;b;1);{1;2;3;4});e;SCAN(EOMONTH(B2;-1);c;LAMBDA(f;g;IF(INDEX(d;MAX(g-1;1);1)=INDEX(d;g;1);EOMONTH(f;0)+1;INDEX(d;g;2))));VSTACK(A1:D1;CHOOSECOLS(HSTACK(d;e);{1;5;3;4})))

Comment: Please change `{1;2;3;4}` to `{1\2\3\4}` and `{1;5;3;4}` into `{1\5\3\4}` @SQLShane. That's how I'd write it when applied to my Dutch Excel.

Answer (score 3):

Please, try the next code. It creates an array of months interval, calculated by difference between the End Date and Period, then place it in the right position of a newly created sheet ("Forecast"). If this sheet already exists (second time when run the code), it is only cleared. The code will process all products existing in A:A column. It should work on all Excel versions:

```
Sub MakeForecast()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, shF As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arrHead, arr, arrD, i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  If sh.name = "Forecast" Then MsgBox "You activated a wrong sheet...": End Sub 'for the case of activating it by mistake
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  arrHead = sh.Range("A1:D1").Value
  arr = sh.Range("A2:D" & lastR).Value2
  
  On Error Resume Next
    Set shF = Worksheets("Forecast") 'check if "Forecast" sheet is already created
  On Error GoTo 0
  If shF Is Nothing Then   'if not, create it and name "Forecast"
        Set shF = Worksheets.Add(After:=sh)
        shF.name = "Forecast"
  Else
        shF.cells.Clear    'if created, clear all its cells contents
  End If
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr) 'iterate between the array rows
        arrD = makeMonthsDateRange(CDate(arr(i, 2)), CDate(arr(i, 4))) 'use the function to create the moths array
        createProdRange shF, arrD, CStr(arr(i, 1)), CDbl(arr(i, 3)), CDate(arr(i, 4)), IIf(i = 1, arrHead, Array("")) 'drop the array content and format a little
  Next i
  shF.Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
  MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

Private Function makeMonthsDateRange(frstD As Date, lastD As Date) As Variant
     Dim countD As Long, arrM
     countD = DateDiff("m", frstD, lastD, vbMonday)
     makeMonthsDateRange = Evaluate("DATE(" & Year(frstD) & ",ROW(1:" & countD & "),1)")
End Function

Sub createProdRange(ws As Worksheet, arrMonths, strProduct As String, cost As Double, endDate As Date, arrH)
   If UBound(arrH) > 0 Then ws.Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(arrH, 2)).Value = arrH
    Dim lastR As Long: lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1
    With ws.Range("A" & lastR, "D" & UBound(arrMonths) + lastR - 1)
        .Columns(1).Value = strProduct
         With .Columns(2)
            .Value2 = arrMonths
            .NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyy"
         End With
         .Columns(3).Value2 = cost
         With .Columns(4)
            .Value2 = endDate
            .NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyy"
         End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it. If something not clear enough, please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.